# Python, количество путей по обходу матрицы, проверяющая система пишет, что при запуске кода происходит ошибка выполнения

Tags: python, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

я написала код по следующей задаче:

```
Черепаха хочет переползти из левого верхнего угла поля размером N на M клеток 
( 1 ≤ N , M ≤ 1000 ) в правый нижний. За один шаг она может переместиться на 
соседнюю клетку вправо или на соседнюю клетку вниз. Определите, сколькими 
различными способами Черепаха может добраться до цели.

Поскольку количество способов, которое нужно найти, может быть очень велико, 
вычислите его по модулю 10 6 + 7 , то есть найдите остаток от деления этого 
числа на 10 6 + 7 .

Входные данные
Входная строка содержит два натуральных числа: размеры поля N и M , 
разделённые пробелом ( 1 ≤ N , M ≤ 1000 ).

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести одно число: количество различных маршрутов 
из левого верхнего угла поля в правый нижний по модулю 10 6 + 7 .

Примеры
входные данные
20 20
выходные данные
16385
```

Написала по ней код:

```
n, m=map(int, input().split()) 
a=[[1]*m for i in range(n)]
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(1, m):
        a[i][j]=a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1] 
print((a[n-1][m-1])%(10**6+7))
```

Но на 4 последних тестах проверяющей системы написано "ошибка выполнения программы" (об ошибке больше ничего не написано), помогите пожалуйста понять, что это за ошибка и исправить код!!!

Comment: Чтобы гигантские числа в расчётах не участвовали, при каждом сложении используйте взятие остатка `a[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1])%1000007 `. Однако к ошибке времени выполнения в Python это привести не может. Ограничения по памяти в задаче есть? От хранения длинных чисел указанное исправление избавит

Comment: Вы бы давали URL, чтоб можно было смотреть, в чем может быть проблема... Выдвинуть версию, через несколько часов дождаться от вас "нет, не работает" — путь очень длинный и не располагающий по нему идти... :)

Comment: Почитайте про треугольник Паскаля и биномиальные коэффициенты. С их помощью задача на Питоне решается в одну строку.

Comment: Табличка, которую вы составляете занимает в памяти более 107MB если *N = M = 1000*. Я предполагаю что ограничение на объём памяти в этой задаче - 64MB. Таблица просто не помещается в память.

Comment: @Настя Вы попробовали предложенное исправление?

Comment: Да, исправила, оформите пожалуйста в форме ответа

Comment: @Настя Оформил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы гигантские числа в расчётах не участвовали, взятие остатка применяйте при каждом сложении:

```
 a[i][j]=(a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1]) % 1000007
```

Кроме того, в расчетах всегда участвует только текущая и предыдущая строка, поэтому хранить всю таблицу не обязательно, а можно выделить память под пару строк, переключая их по чётности индекса:

```
n, m=map(int, input().split())
a=[[1]*m for i in range(2)]
for i in range(1, n):
    last = (i + 1) % 2
    current = i % 2
    for j in range(1, m):
        a[current][j]=(a[last][j] + a[current][j-1]) % 1000007
print(a[(n-1)%2][m-1])
```